# Get data from multiple databases at once

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to `UNION` data from tables with the same name in multiple databases. All databases have the same prefix: `CDNXL_`*(NAME OF DB)*

How would I execute this query against more than one database at at time?

```
SELECT 
    prac_id, 
    prac_name, 
    prace_surname, 
    prac_IDcard, 
    prac_workplace
From prac_nag.CDNXL_ (NAME OF DB) 
where prac_IDcard = @parameter
```

Can this be done with  `'IF'` or `'WHILE'`?

-- Edit
Now I can see my mistake.

I have got 46 Databases with prefix CDNXL_ but one is DB with CDNXL_Configuration, and doesn't have got table was I wanna. How can I skip/ignore this DB?

Comment: Not so bad, but please, please, please write "I" in uppercase... :-)

Comment: :) thx 4 suggestion

Comment: Believe me: If you would feel, how does it look, you wouldn't ever type in an "i" in your entire life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use [cursor or undocumented](https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp_msforeachdb) methods. You can just use dynamic tsql.

```
declare @sqltext nvarchar(max) = N''
declare @parameter varchar(max) = 'define what you want to search here'
select @sqltext += '
SELECT 
    prac_id, 
    prac_name, 
    prace_surname, 
    prac_IDcard, 
    prac_workplace
From '+name+'.dbo.prac_nag 
where prac_IDcard = '''+@parameter+''''
FROM sys.databases
WHERE OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.prac_nag', 'U') IS NOT NULL -- will return only if the table exists
and name like 'CDNXL_%' -- filter your dbs out
print @sqltext
-- once your review the output, uncomment out below
--exec sp_executesql @sqltext
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods you can try is [`sp_msforeachdb`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/). Making some assumptions about your datatypes in the `@table` below...

```
declare @results table (
    prac_id int, 
    prac_name nvarchar(100), 
    prace_surname nvarchar(100), 
    prac_IDcard nvarchar(100), 
    prac_workplace nvarchar(100)
);

insert @results
exec sp_msforeachdb N'
use [?]

if left(''?'',6) = ''CDNXL_'' -- only execute the query against databases 
                              -- that match the naming pattern
    and ''?'' <> ''CDNXL_Configuration''
begin
    select
        prac_id, 
        prac_name, 
        prace_surname, 
        prac_IDcard, 
        prac_workplace
    from prac_nag.[?]
    where prac_IDcard = @parameter; 
end;
';

select * from @results;
```

Comment: THX :) it's work perfectly. For another, I changed syntax - `'CDNXL_'` to `"CDNXL_"`

and

from `prac_nag.[CDNXL_?]` to `prac_nag.[?]`

Comment: fair warning using `ms_foreachdb` - https://sqlblog.org/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp_msforeachdb